# how to write reusable make commands

Tags: makefile

I'm writing some make commands for Terraform. My three commands for plan, apply and destroy are all identical but for one word. Is there a way to have a base definition and replace the work in each?

```
env = "prod"
target_module := $(if $(module), "-target=module.$(module)",)

tf_plan:
    terraform plan -var-file="$(env).tfvars" $(target_module)

tf_apply:
    terraform apply -var-file="$(env).tfvars" $(target_module)

tf_destroy:
    terraform destroy -var-file="$(env).tfvars" $(target_module)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html):

```
tf_plan tf_apply tf_destroy: tf_%:
    terraform $* -var-file="$(env).tfvars" $(target_module)
```

From [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html):

> $* - The stem ... In a static pattern rule, the stem is part of the file name that matched the ‘%’ in the target pattern.

Comment: it looks like going in the direction of what I need. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error as in:  make: Nothing to be done for `tf_plan'.

Comment: Then there must be something else about your makefile or environment that you haven't shown here, or else you didn't use the rule exactly as @Andreas provided, because their example does work as expected.  If you use just the makefile example here and nothing else does it work?  If not you should probably edit your question and add in exactly what you have, what you typed, and the output you got (cut and paste to avoid transcription errors)

Comment: my whole makefile is as in the description. I ran it as : make tf_plan